# Provide http service by wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

This post is origin post at https://stackoverflow.com/q/40018619/306719, but got no attention, and I found this site, so I think here maybe the right place, and I will apply for a redirection for the origin post.

---

I want to provide a http based service to insert new post with extra information, I think wordpress plugin maybe the right place.

However I am not sure how to get started event I read the plugin reference from wordpress.

I think there should be some action like `request_recieve` where I can registered to intercept the request and do my own job, but I can not find that. Also how to avoid blocking the normal wordpress request.

Comment: http based service? May be you can try WP rest api.

Comment: Wordpress provide [HTTP_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API). Check it.

Comment: @bravokeyl: The rest api can not meet my requirement. When I receive a request not only I will validate/insert it to the database but also I will have to do some extra job. And return different response to the client.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: I am not going to `send` http request from wordpress but `receive` request.

Comment: @hguser: HTTP_API, all about http transports(i.e. send, retrieve) not only send. Hope you checked *Helper Functions* section from given HTTP_API link.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: I check that again, and it seems that the `HTTP_API` can be used to make wordpress worked as a client, while want I need is to make wordpress worked as a server with extra endpoints which will handle requests from the client. Something like the `WP rest api`

Answer (score 0):

Now I use the `init` hook to add my own process for the request, and then check the request should be handled by the plugin, if yes, process and exit, if not do nothing. Like this:

```
add_action('init',function(){
  if(should_intercepte_the_request()){
    //process that.
    //exit
    die("foo");
  }else{
    //do nothing
  }
});
```

Then you can access the http by: `http://localhost`

It is recommended that you check the request method, and some access token to make sure the requests are sent by a trusted source.